# Xamarin forms app fails Intune Conditional Access Policy of one Client

Tags: xamarin, single-sign-on, intune

Our app allows Single Sign On(SSO) using the Xamarin's webview component. One of the clients have reported that they are not able to sign in to our app as it fails. But the same SSO if accessed from the device browser, passes the CA policy.
From the logs provided by the customer, it shows that DeviceID is null when called from Xamarin webview but it shows a valid value when called from the device browser.
Can someone help me understand why it is failing on our app alone?

Comment: iOS or Android?  Is it only one specific device or all of them?  Is there any common thread relating to device type or OS version?  Have you tried deleting and re-adding the app from affected devices?  Have you checked if there are any permissions that have been denied for your app?

Comment: It fails on both platforms. It says device is not complaint. From the Intune logs of the customer, the deviceID is null when the SSO Url is called from the webview of our app.

Comment: are you able to replicate this locally?  How is the DeviceID being set?

Comment: No, we don't have the setup to reproduce this. Customer's are using Active directory and Intune for MDM. Device is complaint and they are able to sign in from mobile device browser. Only from our app it fails. 
And we are not setting device ID. When called from the browser it shows the device ID. So, I think it is derived from something else. Not sure if I'm right

Comment: Hi @Karthiga, I wonder if and how you could resolve this! I am dealing with a 3rd party android app that fails SSO. There is a restriction for using [Device-based Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/conditional-access-intune-common-ways-use#device-based-conditional-access) with WebViews. The configuration in the **Company Portal** app to **Enable Browser Access** would allow Chrome to provide the device ID. But for WebView, the doc says: NO. So, I wonder if you could `WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, boolean privateBrowsing)`.

Comment: hi @Karthiga ,
Have you been able to resolve the issue with your Xamarin  app? I am experiencing the same problem with xamarin ios app. If you have found a solution, could you please share it with me?